# How do I get the RGB values of an Image?

Tags: image-processing, graphics, rgb, textures

I am taking a computer graphics class, and I need to work with textures, but I can't use any library to do it. I am stuck on loading the rgb values of the images I need to use (the images can be in any format, jpg, raw, png, etc..) so my question is, which is the easiest way to get the rgb values of an image (of any format) without using any libraries to get this values?? Here is what I found already on the site:

```
    unsigned char *data;
    File *file;

    file = fopen("image.png", "r");//

    data = (unsigned char *)malloc(TH*TV*3); //TH and TV are both 50

    fread(data, TH*TV*3, 1, file);
    fclose(file);

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<TH*TV*3;i++){
       //suposing I have a struct RGB for the rgb values
       RGB.r = data[?];// how do I get the r value
       RGB.g = data[?];// how do I get the g value
       RGB.b = data[?];// how do I get the b value
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: FIRST YOU STOP SHOUTING!

Comment: I missed the part where you were opening a PNG file. The PNG format is complicated, writing code to read it is completely outside the scope of a StackOverflow answer. It's impractical to do without using a library.

Comment: Same goes for JPG and many other formats. There are a few that are easily parseable (PBM/PGM/PNM, TGA, etc.), but most of the more modern ones (especially the ones that focus on compressing images) are not so simple to read without a library.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some framework like [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) there are several options to get the colors or to manipulate an image.

Here I found this example code:

```cpp
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("lenna.png");
for(int i=0; i<img.rows; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<img.cols; j++) {
        // You can now access the pixel value with cv::Vec3b
        std::cout << img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] << " ";
        str::cout << img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1] << " ";
        str::cout << img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But please note that the code above is not very performance, but the code above should give you an idea how to read the pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than iterating through every byte that you read in, you want to iterate every *pixel* which consists of 3 bytes. So replace `i++` with `i+=3`.

```
for(i=0;i<TH*TV*3;i+=3){
   RGB.r = data[i];
   RGB.g = data[i+1];
   RGB.b = data[i+2];
}
```

Comment: An png image is compressed as you should know. So your code above cannot work.

Comment: @rekire, sorry I missed that part. No way you're going to read a PNG without using a library.

Comment: ok, so let's thing in another image format, how about a raw image, or a bmp (I can use the format that I want, I put the png as an example)

Comment: @user2275378, this solution works for raw pixel data without a header. Not a raw camera image which is a different thing altogether and is even more complicated than PNG.

Comment: To let the code above work you need to save the image in RGB888. That should work. Just as a side note: OpenCV would take the image and will convert the image e.g. to RGB888 in memory. There you can also access the raw data.

Comment: @MarkRansom sorry about the SHOUTING :p
Ok, I thing I understood my teacher wrong, he does not want us to use any libraries for doing the textures (like OpenGl), but to load the rgb values of the images I just found out that we can, so now that I know this, which library should I use, thanks for all the answers.